# Connect to server using smart card for client authentication

Tags: openssl, certificate, smartcard, private-key

We developed software where a GUI client connects to an openssl Server using either login/password or a client certificate. We have to implement a new solution which where the the connection establishment is performed by a smart card instead of an embedded certificate.

The problem is that the private key used to sign the client certificate is not exportable.
So, in the server, I don't know how to change the `ssl_ctx_use_privatekey_file` which takes the file containing the private key in the second argument .

Is it possible to deal with smart card authentication using the openssl library?

Comment: The private key file may also be a reference to a private key stored in a PKCS#11 token if I am not mistaken. The exact solution will depend on the specific smart card solution, but Martin's answer is a good starting point.

Comment: In case anybody is here in 2021 or later, searching for smartcard pki authentication, one option can be checked at https://web.signer.digital/home

Answer (score 0):

Look into [ENGINE](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/engine.html) (and possibly [engine_pkcs11](https://www.opensc-project.org/opensc/wiki/engine_pkcs11))

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for your answers it really helped me! I had to switch in another project i finally came back to this stuff.

I dit this :
    ENGINE *engine;
    const char *engine_name = "pkcs11";
    engine = ENGINE_by_id(engine_name);
    rv = ENGINE_init(engine);
  check_ssl_rv("ENGINE_init", rv, 1);
  EVP_PKEY *pkey = NULL;

  pkey = ENGINE_load_private_key(engine, NULL, UI_OpenSSL(), NULL);

  if (!pkey) {
          fprintf(stderr, "Error loading private key);
  }
The problem is about the "id" argument, i don't know how to use it, get it..etc any suggestions? thanks again

Comment: I have a lot of problems configuring all of that.. In fact i forgot to precise that i'm login to linux server from windows client using the smartcard plugged into my PC (containing certificate and the private key associated). For more precisions, i use a dll from my C# client (the dll is written in C with all of the openssl connections). So after a lot of research i found a lot of examples configurating this but all are about configuration Linux. Is it normal that "engine_pkcs11.dll" doesn't exist anymore? do i have to do all my stuff with pkcs11 or CAPI?

Comment: The "right" thing to do would be to use CAPI, especially if you have "native" cards on Windows (with a working Minidriver or CSP). It depends on your requirements (platform integration vs portability etc) but given that you use C# I would use CAPI.

Comment: But for the time being, this question in its current from has exhausted itself and should be closed.

Comment: The provided links are dead and you did not repost any information from the links.